# How to use substring function in R when you have a vector?

Tags: r, string, vector, integer, substring

I need to use `substring` function to extract characters by location from a data frame as shown in the picture:

[image]

Here is the code that I used:

```
substring(df$Text1,
          df$'Location of Different Letters',
          df$'Location of Different Letters')
```

`substring` function introduced `NA`s in every row where the numbers are in character string format. Any suggestion how to make it work? Using `as.integer` on column "Location of Different Letters" doesn't work because of the `c()` and `:`

Comment: What class is `Location of different letters`?

Comment: I have it in character and list format the method above was applied to the character column and of course didn't work for the list column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `Location of different letters` as a character column, which will make things a bit of ugly as we have to use `eval(parse(..))`.

```
## create a index list
cmd <- paste0("list(", toString(df$"Location of different letters"), ")")
# [1] "list(4, c(1,6,7,8), 3:6)"
ind <- eval(parse(text = cmd))
## split your strings
s <- strsplit(df$Text1, "")
## use `mapply`
set1 <- mapply("[", s, ind)

## now compare with `Text2` to get different letters
set2 <- strsplit(df$Text2, "")
mapply(function (a, b) paste0(setdiff(a, b), collapse = ""), set1, set2)
# [1] "d"    "FADX" "123"
```

---

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Text1 = c("abcd", "FxyznADX", "Don123"),
                 Text2 = c("abc", "xyzn", "Don"),
                 "Location of different letters" = c("4", "c(1,6,7,8)", "3:6"),
                 check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works if you have a vector of values in your column of `Location of different letters`.

```
out <- sapply(c(1, 6, 7, 8), FUN = function(x) substring("FxyznADX", first = x, last = x))

do.call(paste, args = list(as.list(out), collapse = ""))
[1] "FADX"
```

If you have a character/factor for the values, you may need to resort to `eval(parse(...))`.

```
sapply(eval(parse(text = "c(1, 6, 7, 8)")), FUN = function(x) substring("FxyznADX", first = x, last = x))

[1] "F" "A" "D" "X"
```